# CDN Causing IFrame Load Issues

Tags: javascript, iframe, cdn

I am trying to load a html file in an iframe but ever since I loaded our site's resources to a CDN, it is now being blocked by the browser.

Here is an example (supplement facts on the right side is not loading fully): https://www.prosupps.com/products/aminolinx

This is the error I'm getting from the console:

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.prosupps.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at resizeIframe (https://cdn.prosupps.com/media/js/54d03508885a150fb0a1fa2ded94c4e8.js:21106:57) at HTMLIFrameElement.onload (https://www.prosupps.com/products/aminolinx:677:248)

Can anybody help me find a solution?

Here is the specific line of code that's causing issues now.

```
 function resizeIframe(e)
{e.style.height=e.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+"px"}
```

Here is the iframe code:

```
 <iframe name="aminolinx-sample-supplement-facts" id="supplement-facts" 
src="{{media url="wysiwyg/prosupps/supplement-facts/AminoLinx-Mango-
Passion-Fruit-Sample-Supplement-Facts.html"}}" frameborder="0" 
scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: Some pop-up and iframe related browser functionalities only work if the content is from the same origin. I'm not sure what is going on here, but my guess is you are using one of those functionalities. Moving the iframe content back to the same origin will do the trick.

Comment: Content is loading from a CDN...if I move content off of CDN it will work but there goes the reason for a CDN.  :/

Comment: You could look into ffeast his solution. One more option would be to move the complete website to CDN, and only do api communication via REST to your own server. That way the cross origin problem doesn't exist anymore, because the only origin related to the iframe will be the CDN.

Comment: Since both origins share the same host, you can set `document.domain=https://prosupps.com` on both cdn and your web site.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access):

> JavaScript APIs such as iframe.contentWindow, window.parent,
>   window.open and window.opener allow documents to directly reference
>   each other. When the two documents do not have the same origin, these
>   references provide very limited access to Window and Location objects

This is why when you offloaded your resources to CDN your JS got broken. 
You'll either need to move your right block back from CDN or resort to [postmessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between frames

> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin
>   communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a
>   pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded
>   within it